# React native - Dropdown text alignment issue

Tags: react-native, dropdown, text-alignment

```
 <Dropdowndata={linkedToList != null ?
linkedToList.map((item, key) => ({
label: item.claim_slug_id, value: item.claim_id
})) : submittingOption}
textInputStyle={{ marginTop: 0, height: 42, fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular', color: color.black }}
itemTextStyle={{ fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular', color: color.black }}
selectedItemTextStyle={{ fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular', color: color.dark_color }}
disableSelectionTick
disableSort
removeLabel
enableSearch
underlineColor={color.bg_color}
value={selectedTypeOfClaim}
onChange={(value, index) => {
}
/>
```

The issue is that, in the Dropdown menu the text is not align in case of 2 line.
While it's working fine in case of single line.

[image]